# How to override local function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Suppose this code in some JavaScript file:

```
const localFunc = function(v) {  if(v.b) console.log(v.b) else console.log('wrong!'); }
var myObj = {
       myFunc: function(v) { localFunc({a:v}); }
}
```

Suppose we have access to `myObj` but not to `localFunc`.

We want to execute `localFunc({b:v})` instead of `localFunc({a:v})`;

Is possible to do that?

Comment: There's no index for anonymous functions so, if it was created somewhere private, you won't be able to access or change it. (It's entirely possible to create running javascript that isn't accessible/visible by other javascript.)

Comment: It's a little hard to visualize what you're trying to accomplish with the code given since both of these are in the same scope and thus both accessible. Can you please provide an example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the thing you actually want to do?

Comment: @VLAZ it does not matter *my* problem, I can solve it. It's a generic question about JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is possible to do that?

No. If you do not have access to `localFunc`, you can't change something that's hardcoded into `myObj.myFunc`'s call to `localFunc` (in this example, the property name used when creating the object to pass to it). You'd have to replace `myObj.myFunc`, and to do that, you'd have to have access to `localFunc`.

Comment: chatGPT tried with Proxy, eval and also Function.prototype.call, are you sure is not possible with something like that?

Comment: @Enrique - Yes. Neither of those is relevant to what you're looking to do. (ChatGPT will frequently just pick things from its training data that are completely irrelevant. It's important to understand that it's a *language* system, not a *knowledge* system.) You can't *change* the code inside `myObj.myFunc` (you can only replace the function), and you can't reach inside a private scope to get access to `localFunc`. So unless `localFunc` actually **is** accessible to the code your'e trying to do this in even though you said it isn't, I'm afraid there's no way to do it. :-)

Answer (score -2):

First idea which come to mine was Overloading , which JavaScript Does not support.

Long Story Short , no you can't do this using javaScript.

**The alternative to overload**

Some alternatives:

- Rename the method name: if the same method name is creating some
  confusion, try to rename the methods to create a meaningful name
  better than createDocument, like: createLicenseDriveDocument,
  createDocumentWithOptionalFields, etc. Of course, this can lead you
  to giant method names, so this is not a solution for all cases.
- Use    static methods. This approach is kind of similar if compared
  to the    first alternative above. You can use a meaningful names to
  each case    and instantiate the document from a static method on
  Document, like:    Document.createLicenseDriveDocument().
- Create a common interface: you can create a single method called
  createDocument(InterfaceDocument interfaceDocument) and create
  different implementations for InterfaceDocument. Per example:
  createDocument(new DocumentMinPagesCount("name")). Of course you
  don't need a single implementation for each case, because you can
  create more than one constructor on each implementation, grouping
  some fields that makes sense on that implementation. This pattern is
  called telescoping constructors.

Source: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/235096/how-to-avoid-excessive-method-overloading

Comment: sure, i will add reference on that

Comment: Overloading has nothing to do with what the OP"s asking about.

Comment: sure, i would use the source and use text instead of screenshots

Comment: oh, that's my misunderstanding . sorry about that.